# Objects move when Bake Simulation

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I am new in Blender and I have a problem related to the position of the Objects when I Bake a Rigid Body Simulation.

I have a "wall" object with Rigid Body and I want to Bake the Simulation. [image: Rigid Body]

But when I create the Bake (Object/Ridig Body/Bake to keyframes) the original position of the object change.[image: rigid problem]

Any ideas? I think I don't have any Parents that could make a Position problem. Also, I Applied Transforms before to create the Rigid Body, I Set the Origin to the center, recreate my object and nothing helps.
I have the same problem with many Objects in this scene.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you modify the location of the object on a keyframe besides 0?

Comment: No, the object doens't have any Keyframe, the only keyframes appear when I make the Bake (they are created by Blender) and they start at 0.